# What would be the disadvantage behavior if i made all request with ajax in my Web Application

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I made my project in school with all request methods and get methods through ajax. Also i used data tables with ajax to do my CRUD related entities. What would be the disadvantage of my app?

Is there any bad behavior in my web project because i used ajax all the time?
I am using CODEIGNITER Framework and made ajax all for database methods like post and get. Please some piece of advice.

Comment: There are plenty of 1 page apps on the web. The only issue I see is maintainability and SEO. But as a backend system the later doesn't really matter and if done correctly a JS based site can be as maintainable as a multi-page site. It is entirely up to your needs/wants. With that being said, your question is way too broad for stack and would be better suited on a forum elsewhere.

Comment: hi @Alex , is there no problem in making heavy request in Ajax ?. Does this affect the runtime of my application ?

Comment: any heavy request ajax or otherwise will affect your runtime. querying a database and getting about 1million rows either in a "normal" scenario or via ajax will take equally as long (pretty much). you would approach that kindof scenario with a "load more" function where in a "normal" scenario you would use pagination. in any scenario keep your requests small even if that means you have to do more. but again, depends on your classification of heavy/light loads.

Answer (score 0):

One Problem might be that there are users (or devices/browsers) out there who block scripts. For those your App wont work.

Comment: if anyone in 2018 blocks scripts they probably shouldn't be using the internet imo

Comment: Ok - i respect your opinion. But imho its useful in terms of data privacy and safe browsing, since you can switch of tracking with it and random third party script loading/executing. NoScript for example which is only one of many script blockers has currently 868,863 users (07.2018) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/

Comment: as I understand it "no script" doesn't block all js... just the ones that you don't specify as trusted. if someone really wanted to block all js they could just disable it in the settings. that being said, it just makes no sense to me. if you are afraid of the potential tracking/malicious js on the web then you are either overly paranoid or don't have any kind of antivirus. the former is just no way to live, and the later is a must have.

Comment: to me it is perfectly acceptable to not even consider those without js enabled and to just issue a notice saying "You need js to access this site". If they don't like it so be it. If a company as large and successful as Facebook/Instagram can get away with it who has 2.19 billion monthly active users I think the majority of us should be just fine.